# React Native - animation with parallel translation and scale

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-animated

I want to make an animation where an image should scale and move to the center at the same time. However, the final position is not correct. If I don't have scale, the translation works perfectly. I want to center the image, so  (screenW / 2 - IMAGE_RADIUS * SCALE) should be correct.

(1) before: https://ibb.co/efjAW8, (2): after: https://ibb.co/bUL64T

code:

```
pressedImage = () => {
const deltaX = (screenW / 2 - IMAGE_RADIUS * SCALE) - origX;
const deltaY = (screenH / 2 - IMAGE_RADIUS * SCALE - 30) - origY;


Animated.parallel([
  Animated.timing(this.state.scaleAnimatedValue, {
    toValue: SCALE,
    easing: Easing.ease,
    duration: 1000,
  }),
  Animated.timing(this.state.animTransX,{
    toValue: deltaX,
    easing: Easing.ease,
    duration: 1000,
  }),
  Animated.timing(this.state.animTransY,{
    toValue: deltaY,
    easing: Easing.ease,
    duration: 1000,
  }),
]).start();
}

render() {
...
<ImageView style={
        {
          transform: [
              {
                translateX: this.state.animTransX,
              },
              {
                translateY: this.state.animTransY,
              },
              {
                scale: this.state.scaleAnimatedValue,
              },

            ], 
          }} source={{ uri: gist.author.avatarUrl }} />
}
```

How can I achieve this? I've tried with matrix transformations and setNativeProps but failed miserably. This should be a simple thing...